# Download OSM data with QuickOSM and QGIS Modeler example and/or tutorial to share

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I would like to automatically search and save my results (11 layers) via the QuickOSM plugin using the Qgis Graphical Modeler. Could anyone help me with some already prepared example or some tutorial on this?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? QuickOSM in Processing is quite different between QGIS 2 and QGIS 3

Comment: Hi Gustry! I am using QGIS version 3.4.4, if you have any information about this issue I will appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: Yes I have some info. I'm the developer of QuickOSM. I will try to answer soon

Comment: Can you add some info about what kind of queries? What kind of tag do you expect in the output (all of them, a subset of OSM tags)? Do you want to use the same extent? Different extent? Different city names? Is the query the same among your 11 layers?